# Extracting elements from a list column

Tags: pyspark

I have a column which is a list of lists `ix`, and another column which contains lists `users`.  I'd like to use `ix` as an index for `users`.  Shown below is a little example.

```
 l = [('store1', [[0, 1], [2, 3]], [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006])]
 df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(l,('store','ix','users'))

+------+--------------------+--------------------+
| store|                  ix|               users|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+
|store1|[WrappedArray(0, ...|[1001, 1002, 1003...|
+------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I'd like the output to be

```
want =  [('store1', [[0, 1], [2, 3]], [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006], [[1001,1002],[1003,1004]])]
want = sqlContext.createDataFrame(want,('store','ix','users','new_col'))
```

Its almostas if I did `users[ix]`.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to do it with an udf.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType

def get_users_from_ix(ixs_array, users):
    output_array = []
    for ixs in ixs_array:
        output = []
        for ix in ixs:
            output.append(users[ix])
        output_array.append(output)
    return output_array

get_users_from_idx_udf = F.udf(get_users_from_idx, ArrayType(ArrayType(IntegerType())))

df_result = df.select('*', get_users_from_idx_udf(F.col('ix'), F.col('users')))
```

This should work.